# Is it possible to add url in window.history object?

Tags: javascript, history, back

So far I've seen only by URL `hashChange` envent, and I'm not interested in that (Because I use BlackBerry 5.0 native browser and it does not have this event support).

For example, Just open your browser first time, then type http://yourdomain.com/page1.html in address bar, then hit enter( or go).
It will open that page, now can we add page2.html in history? so that if user press browser back button, I can redirect him to page2.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript#quickIDX8). It's a read only object.

Answer (score 0):

No. History is a read-only object.

Check this link if you need more info:

- http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/history.shtml

Some tip: you can use cookies for such goal.